# RocksDB exception in Kafka Streams

Tags: lambda, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

In a simple Kafka Stream program when I am using the below code, it works without throwing any error:

```
      KTable<String, Long> result= source.mapValues(textLine
      ->textLine.toLowerCase()) .flatMapValues(lowercasedTextLine ->
      Arrays.asList(lowercasedTextLine.split(" "))) .selectKey((ignoredKey,word) ->
      word) .groupByKey() .count("Counts");

      result.to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long(), "wc-output");
```

However when I am using the below code I am getting error:

```
    KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream("wc-input");
    source.groupBy((key, word) -> word).windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5000))).count()
            .toStream().map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(key.key(), value))
            .to("wc-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
```

> Exception in thread
>   "streams-wordcount-b160d715-f0e0-42ee-831e-0e4eed7e9424-StreamThread-1"
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in
>   process. taskId=1_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000006,
>   topic=streams-wordcount-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002-repartition,
>   partition=0, offset=0     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.process(AssignedTasks.java:403)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:317)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:942)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:822)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744)
>   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException:
>   Error opening store
>   KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002:1553472000000 at location
>   \tmp\kafka-streams\streams-wordcount\1_0\KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002\KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002:1553472000000
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:204)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.Segment.openDB(Segment.java:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.Segments.getOrCreateSegment(Segments.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.put(RocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBWindowStore$RocksDBWindowBytesStore.put(RocksDBWindowStore.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBWindowStore$RocksDBWindowBytesStore.put(RocksDBWindowStore.java:34)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:33)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore$1.apply(CachingWindowStore.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.evict(NamedCache.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.maybeEvict(ThreadCache.java:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.put(ThreadCache.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.put(CachingWindowStore.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.put(CachingWindowStore.java:36)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.put(MeteredWindowStore.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamWindowAggregate$KStreamWindowAggregateProcessor.process(KStreamWindowAggregate.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:216)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: Failed to create
>   dir:
>   H:\tmp\kafka-streams\streams-wordcount\1_0\KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002\KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002:1553472000000:
>   Invalid argument  at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(Native Method)  at
>   org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(RocksDB.java:231)    at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:197)

Comment: please improve the formatting of your code. This will make it easier to read and answer your question.

Comment: seems like Kafka Streams is not able to create a states store directory. You could try and change the state store directory to another path, and see if this fixes your problem.

Comment: Which Kafka Streams version are you using?

Comment: This is still happening on Centos 7 with Kafka Version 2.1.0

Answer (score 2):

When you use a windowed aggregation, stores a named differently, and there is a bug in Kafka `1.0.0` affecting Windows OS: the name for windowed stores contains a `:` that is not allowed on Windows OS. The bug is fixed in version `1.0.1` and `1.1.0`

Cf. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6167